# How to convert a Fragment to a Activity Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, activity-oncreateview

I have a working app using threads in fragments, the thing is I need to change the layout. It's not gonna be a Fragment anymore but a standard Activity.

My big problem is that I don't know exactly where to place what's in "onViewCreated" and "onCreateView" so it's crashing when I call "connect to device" which's placed on "onCreateView". Probably because it's too early or something.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_2, container, false);

    //Linking layout views
    connectToDevice = view.findViewById(R.id.connect_to_device);
    startRecording = view.findViewById(R.id.start_recording);
    stopRecording = view.findViewById(R.id.stop_recording);
    connectedToDevice = view.findViewById(R.id.connected_to_device);
    mAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(container.getContext(), activeDevices);
    imgEkoDevice = view.findViewById(R.id.img_ekodevice);

    //Enable bluetooth and start scanning thread
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        btAdapter.enable();
    }

    //Layout setup
    connectedToDevice.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.welcome_to_scopefy));

    //Thread setup to search for device
    scanningThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Log.i(AppConstants.TAG, "scanning...");
            LibCore.getInstance(ConnectDeviceActivity.this).startScanningForDevices(new EkoDeviceScan() {
                @Override
                public void foundDevice(BLEDevice bleDevice) {
                    //Log.i(AppPreferences.log, "foundDevice: " + bleDevice.toString());
                    if(activeDevices.isEmpty()){
                        //Adding first device to list
                        activeDevices.add(bleDevice);
                    }
                    else{
                        int i = 0;
                        newDevice = true;
                        //Checks if its already on the list
                        while(i < activeDevices.size() && newDevice){
                            if(activeDevices.get(i).getAddress().equals(bleDevice.getAddress())){
                                newDevice = false;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        if(newDevice){
                            activeDevices.add(bleDevice);
                        }
                    }

                    //Show list and dismiss search dialog
                    if(connect){
                        showDeviceListDialog();
                        if(emptyListDialog != null){
                            emptyListDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        connect = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ConnectDeviceActivity.this).registerReceiver(mDeviceReceiver, new IntentFilter(Parameters.DEVICE_REFRESH_DATA));

    //Starting scanning background to speed up
    if(LibCore.getInstance(ConnectDeviceActivity.this).getCurrentConnectedDevice() == null){
        scanningThread.start();
        LibCore.getInstance(ConnectDeviceActivity.this).setFiltering(true);
        connected = false;
    } else {
        mEkoDevice = LibCore.getInstance(ConnectDeviceActivity.this).getCurrentConnectedDevice();
        connected = true;
    }

    //Broadcast receiver for patientId
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ConnectDeviceActivity.this).registerReceiver(mPatientReceiver, new IntentFilter(Parameters.PATIENT_ID));

    //Listeners and receivers for device connection
    LibCore.getInstance(ConnectDeviceActivity.this).setBatteryListener(new EkoDeviceBatteryLevel() {
        @Override
        public void deviceUpdatedBatteryLevel(float v) {
            Log.i("HUEBR123", "updateou bat");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ConnectDeviceActivity.this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(Parameters.DEVICE_REFRESH_DATA).putExtra(Parameters.DEVICE_UPDATED_BATTERY_LEVEL, v));
        }
    });

    LibCore.getInstance(ConnectDeviceActivity.this).setVolumeListener(new EkoDeviceVolume() {
        @Override
        public void deviceUpdatedVolumeLevel(int i) {
            Log.i("HUEBR123", "updateou vol");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ConnectDeviceActivity.this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(Parameters.DEVICE_REFRESH_DATA).putExtra(Parameters.DEVICE_UPDATED_VOLUME_LEVEL, i));
        }
    });



    //Settings
    userSettingsDAO = new UserSettingsDAO(ConnectDeviceActivity.this);
    settings = userSettingsDAO.getUserSettings();

    //Button's listeners
    connectToDevice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            connect = true;
            scanningThread.run();
            showDeviceListEmptyDialog();
        }
    });

    startRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i(AppConstants.TAG, "starting recording...");
            stopped = false;
            startRecording();
            //startPlayRecordThroughEko();
            startRecording.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            stopRecording.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recording = true;

            settings = userSettingsDAO.getUserSettings();
            settings.getRecordingLength();

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task  = new StopRecordingTask();
            timer.schedule(task, settings.getRecordingLength() * 1000);
            Log.i(AppConstants.TAG, "#timer starting for " + settings.getRecordingLength() + " seconds");
        }
    });

    stopRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                mEkoOutputAudioByteListener = null;
                mAudioFileOutputStream.close();
                writeWAVHeader(mCachedAudioRecordingFile, 4000);
                //writeWAVHeader(mCachedECGRecordingFile, 500);
                stopOutputtingAudioDataPoints();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            startRecording.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            stopRecording.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            recording = false;

            short[] output;
            output = new short[outData.size() * 32];
            for(int i=0; i<outData.size(); i++){
                for(int j=0; j<32; j++){
                    output[i] = outData.get(i)[j];
                }
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectDeviceActivity.this, AuscultationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("output", output);
            intent.putExtra("patient-id", patientId);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Log.i(AppConstants.TAG, "OUPUTLEN: " + output.length);
            if(!stopped) {
                stopped = true;
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

//This overridden method makes DynamicWaveformViews avoid crashing
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    dynamicWaveformView = (DynamicWaveformView) view.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_waveform_view);
    dynamicWaveformView.init();

    mAudioThread = new HandlerThread("AudioThread");
    mAudioThread.start();
    mAudioHandler = new Handler(mAudioThread.getLooper());

    //updateView again for consistency (mDeviceBroadcast may be too much but still works)
    updateView(connected);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mEkoDevice = new EkoDevice("DUMMY_DEVICE", "0");
    buyNow = findViewById(R.id.buyNow);
    back = findViewById(R.id.back_icon);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    buyNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });

    changeAudioAmplitudeScaleFactor(8);

    mPlayerManager = new PlayerManager();
    mPlayerManager.onCreate();

    LibCore.getInstance(ConnectDeviceActivity.this).setFiltering(true);
}
```

trying to place at the bottom of "onCreate" it gives me the following error:

PopupWindow $BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token null is not valid

Comment: Show entire Activity, where is 'onCreate'?

Comment: it's too big, but the position where my "onCreate" is matters? Updated the questions showing the method

Answer (score 0):

Regarding you error

> PopupWindow $BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token null is
>   not valid

Maybe add that code in the Activity `onResume()` lifecykle method instead of `onCreate` if it need to run more then one time

Move the `scanningThread`, `BluetoothAdapter` and `LocalBroadcastManager` `LibCore` everything to the 'onCreate()' . The 'onCreateView()' should only have the `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_2, container, false);`

The `onCreate()` only initiate stuff hook up local variables views and set `clicklisteners`. Like all the one-time-stuff. Going from Fragment to Activity is basically almost the same since they have the same lifecykle methods

Check this nice explanation about [the-android-lifecycle-cheat-sheet](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/the-android-lifecycle-cheat-sheet-part-iii-fragments-afc87d4f37fd)

Comment: you mean what's in "onCreateView" and "onViewCreated" should come on "onResume" and in this exact order right?

Comment: Move the scanningThread, BluetoothAdapter and LocalBroadcastManager LibCore everything to the onCreate() . The onCreateView() should only have the 'view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_2, container, false);'

Comment: The "onCreate()" only initiate stuff hook up local variables views and set clicklisteners. Like all the one-time-stuff. Going from Fragment to Activity is basically almost the same since they have the same lifecykle methods